# Datastax : All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We are having 8 node datastax cluster, while starting to thrift server we are getting  All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)

```
ERROR 2017-12-30 21:16:16,317 org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper: Failed to start or submit Spark application
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.InternalServerException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522) ~[hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar:1.2.1.spark2]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:189) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:258) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:359) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:263) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:39) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive(HiveSharedState.scala:38) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:43) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.metadataHive(HiveSessionState.scala:43) ~[spark-hive_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLEnv$.init(SparkSQLEnv.scala:62) ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2$.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala:81) ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala) ~[spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$DseSparkSubmit$$runMain(DseSparkSubmit.scala:733) ~[dse-spark-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(DseSparkSubmit.scala:177) ~[dse-spark-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmit$.submit(DseSparkSubmit.scala:202) ~[dse-spark-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmit$.main(DseSparkSubmit.scala:111) ~[dse-spark-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper$.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala:116) ~[dse-spark-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala) [dse-spark-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
Caused by: com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.InternalServerException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
        at com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.DseFsJsonProtocol$ThrowableReader$.read(DseFsJsonProtocol.scala:236) ~[dse-dsefs-common-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
        at com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.DseFsJsonProtocol$ThrowableReader$.read(DseFsJsonProtocol.scala:211) ~[dse-dsefs-common-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
        at spray.json.JsValue.convertTo(JsValue.scala:31) ~[spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
        at com.datastax.bdp.fs.rest.RestResponse$stateMachine$macro$281$1.apply(RestResponse.scala:48) ~[dse-dsefs-common-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
        at com.datastax.bdp.fs.rest.RestResponse$stateMachine$macro$281$1.apply(RestResponse.scala:44) ~[dse-dsefs-common-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36) ~[scala-library-2.11.11.jar:na]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:408) ~[netty-all-4.0.42.Final.jar:4.0.42.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:455) ~[netty-all-4.0.42.Final.jar:4.0.42.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140) ~[netty-all-4.0.42.Final.jar:4.0.42.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
ERROR 2017-12-30 21:16:17,048 org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerExecutorAdded(1514668577045,1,org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.ExecutorData@adac7383)
ERROR 2017-12-30 21:16:17,108 org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerBlockManagerAdded(1514668577108,BlockManagerId(1, , 40533),384093388)
```

Comment: can you check whether Cassandra is running or not

Comment: Thanks :). I have checked cassandra is running fine.

Answer (score 2):

The error is being thrown by the Metastore attempting to setup a directory in DSEFS and failing. We can see the DSEFS root here

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.InternalServerException:
  com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: 
    All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
```

The most common cause of this is that the Replication on the DSEFS based key-space is not configured such that a `LOCAL` consistency request could not succeed from the node in question. I would check the replication and make sure that if you are using *NetworkTopologyStrategy* that the DC name matches the current DC. If you have multiple DC's and are using *SimpleStrategy* this would also cause breaks.

Comment: Great insight Russ!  Good to hear from you again!

Comment: Also check section "Procedure" for step-by-step instructions: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/analytics/configUsingDsefs.html